# Why URL params still be added to URL when set to None with robotframework-requests library

Tags: python-requests, robotframework

In requests library it says dictionary key whose value is None will not be added to the URL’s query string. I sent get request with robotframework-requests library as below:

Test case:

```
 Get Places Id Reviews    ${id}    ${data}    limit=99    page=0
```

keyword

```
Get Places Id Reviews

    [Arguments]    ${id}    ${before}=None    ${limit}=None    ${sort}=None    ${page}=None

    ${para}    Create Dictionary    before=${before}    limit=${limit}    sort=${sort}   page=${page}
    ${url}    Create Session    testingUrl    ${testURL}    headers=${header}    timeout=10
    ${response}    Get Request    testingUrl    /places/${id}/reviews    params=${para}
    log    ${response.url}
```

The log value is: `http://xx.xx.com/places/250707/reviews?before=2019-12-31T16%3A02%3A52.000Z&limit=99&sort=None&page=0`

Why is `sort=None` added to the URL?

Comment: At a guess, because something in that library is stringifying `None` to `"None"` (or never parsing the input to `None` in the first place), but have you done any debugging?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes. for example, not send the limit when invoke the keyword and get the limit type in keyword,  return limit is NoneType

Answer (score 2):

It is because when you do `${sort}=None`, you are setting the default value to the *string* `"None"` not the python value `None`. You have to remember that this is robot framework syntax, not python syntax.

You need to set the default values using robot's built-in variable `${None}`, like in the following example:

```
[Arguments]    ${id}    ${before}=${None}    ${limit}=${None}    ${sort}=${None}    ${page}=${None}
```